# Postgresql Select Query solution

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can anyone help me with this scenario ?

Actual Table

```
rrno         | filename    | type       | amount  | element
--------------------------------------------------------
000000000001 | 00dww       | 0200       | 500      | 45
000000000001 | d00dww      | 0200       | 700      | 456
000000000001 | addww       | 0100       | 250      | 7236
000000000001 | qc5gdw      | 0400       | 431      | 173
012600003598 | q979wa      | 0110       | 050      | --
```

Current Query

```sql
select rrno,filename,type,amoumt 
from table 
where type in ('0220) 
  and amount in ('500','700');
```

Result for Current query

```
rrno         | filename    | type       | amount  | element
--------------------------------------------------------
000000000001 | 00dww       | 0200       | 500      | 45
000000000001 | d00dww      | 0200       | 700      | 456
```

after getting the above results i want to check whether
rrno field 000000000001 has type '0100'  with amount 050.
How to create it in single query ?

Comment: Huh?  Please show the results that you want.  It is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: updated.. can u check

Comment: I still have no idea what "i want to check" means in terms of the results you want.

Comment: i want something like self join. first it needs to get the filename and rrno based on the type(0200) and amount based on condition which i already have. then it should take the result rrno and check whether the particular rrn has type(0100) and return the filename

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that you want `exists`:

```
select rrno, filename, type, amoumt 
from mytable t
where type = '0220' and amount in ('500', '700') and exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.rrno = t.rrno and t1.type = '0100' and t1.amount = '050'
)
```

Starting from your existing query, this filters the resultset on rows for which another row exists in the table with the same `rrno`, `type` `'0100'`  and `amount` `'050'`.

I find quite suprising that a column called `amount` would be of a string datatype. If it's a number, then remove the single quotes around the values.